# c-program: curl failed writing body

Tags: c, libcurl

In my c program I try to get data from my local webserver using libcurl.
This is my code:

```
int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost:3000/employees/2" );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data );
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    ...
}
```

The callback function write_data looks like that:

```
size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) { 
    return size;
}
```

When libcurl calls my callback function "buffer" contains the data expected.
But I'm facing the error:

```
Failed writing body ( 1!= 105)
Closing connection
curl_easy_perform() failed: res = 23
error = failed writing received data to disk/application
```

It works when I'm not setting a callback function.

The curl tutorial says:
*libcurl offers its own default internal callback that will take care of the data if you don't set the callback with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION. It will then simply output the received data to stdout.*

But since I was setting a callback I don't understand why curl apparently tries to write my data nevertheless?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly you lack permissions? Any way to get further diagnostic information from that error?

Comment: Should you be returning `size` or `nmemb`? This is where taking to the duck can help... See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Read the documentation. You must return `size * nitems;`.

Answer (score 3):

The write_data() function must return bytes received which is size * nmemb. Apparently it is being passed a size of 1 and an nmemb set to 105. You are returning 1, so curl is saying that it is not enough bytes since 1 != 105.

Comment: You are right. write_data() is now returning size * nmemb and it works fine. Thank you!   Unfortunately my reputation is too petty to vote your answer up.